# How to debug phonegap windows phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, debugging, cordova, windows-phone-8, weinre

I'm new to windows phone development and found that I don't know how to debug a cordova/phonegap app with windows phone emulator.

I found out that using `weinre` ([from here](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)) it's possible to debug app, but still haven't found how to connect it with emulator (Using `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/#anonymus"></script>` in index.html have not worked)

So, I have 2 possible answers to 2 possible questions:

1) How can I debug my cordova/phonegap app for windows phone?

2) If using weinre, how can I make it work so I can debug my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have created the Windows Phone project in VS. If you can run it on the device then it should work with the following. Taken from this site: http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.cz/2013/03/how-to-debug-windows-phone-html5-apps.html

> You can verify if the server started by opening a browser page and
>   loading 127.0.01:8080 (8080 is the default port for Weinre). If you
>   are seeing this page then the server is running:
>
> Now click on the Debug Client User Interface link where you will be
>   able to see if any client is connected and debug the connected
>   clients. Let's create the Windows Phone HTML5 application. Use the SDK
>   template to create a new project, open the page index.html inside the
>   folder Html and add this line to the head section:
>
> `<script src="http://[the server
>   ip]:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>`
>
> replace [the server ip] with the IP of the PC running the Winre server
>   and run the application. If everything went as we expected in the
>   Debug Client user Interface on the Server we should see one Target
>   connected:
>
> Once the target Windows Phone page is connected you can inspect and
>   change the DOM in real-time

Failing that you can always run the site in IE11 and change its settings to emulate a Windows Phone device, then use the inbuilt IE debug tools, but that obviously doesn't debug on the device...